# How can I use the exact same array from one service in two controllers?

Tags: angularjs, service

I have this code:

controller:

```
function deleteRootCategory(){
 $scope.rootCategories[0] = '';
}

function getCategories(){
  categoryService.getCategories().then(function(data){
    $scope.rootCategories = data[0];
    $scope.subCategories = data[1];
    $scope.titles = data[2];
  });
}

getCategories();
```

service:

```
var getCategories = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method:"GET",
        url:"wikiArticles/categories"
        }).then(function(result){
          deferred.resolve(result);
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
  <div ng-repeat="root in rootCategories"> {{root}} </div>
  <div ng-repeat="sub in subCategories"> {{sub}} </div>
  <div ng-repeat="title in titles">{{title}}</div>
</div>
```

html2:

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
 <div ng-include src="html"></div>
 <button ng-click="deleteRootCategory()">Del</button>
</div>
```

When I click the deleteRootCategory-button the array $scope.rootCategories is updated, but the view won't ever change.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to have a broadcast event set up when the value is changed in the service. Something like this.

```
.service("Data", function($http, $rootScope) {
  var this_ = this, 
      data;

  $http.get('wikiArticles/categories', function(response) {
    this_.set(response.data);
  }

  this.get = function() {
    return data;
  }

  this.set = function(data_) {
    data = data_;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:data-change');
  }

});
```

Have both controllers waiting for the event, and using the set to make any changes to the array.

```
$rootScope.$on('event:data-change', function() {
    $scope.data = Data.get();
}

$scope.update = function(d) {
  Data.set(d);
}
```

Comment: No words can describe what I'm feeling now! Thanks a lot! :)